# Is it valid that localhost appears in multiple lines in linux hosts file?

Tags: linux, hosts

hosts file:

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain

192.168.30.133 localhost machinename

Is it valid that localhost appears in multiple lines?

Comment: This might be valid, but it probably won't do what you want. [What is the real problem you are trying to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a name can have multiple IP addresses But it wouldn't work as in DNS because it will only return the first match.

Comment: thanks, then if I type localhost in browser how to get resolved?

Comment: @performanceuser I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't going to hurt anything, especially in the way you show it with your loopback address and then the local machine address.